# Collision and rectangles/line intersection

Tags: c#, vector, xna, collision-detection, rectangles

I'm doing collision detection for a game, The levels are randomly generated from blocks each with its own bounding box. My collision detection is ok except sometimes, the player ship can collide with 2 or more blocks at the same time and I need to work out which one it hit 1st.

Ive already worked out that If I find the corner of the ship bounding box thats in its movement direction, and then draw a line in the opposite direction of the ships movement vector from that corner (red line on diagram), the intersection point thats *furthest away* on that line will be on the 1st box hit.
I just don't know how to program that logic!

What I have to work with

- List of the bounding boxes (Rectangles) collided with
- ships movement (Vector2)
- Ships bounding box(Reactangle)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be: Add another set of bounding boxes to the ship that are smaller and more acurate. If collision occurs, you should then start checking into the scale of smaller bounding boxes.
From what I understand, many games do that to avoid unneccasary collision checks, but have a way to determin collisions more acurately when they occur.

Comment: Yeah, thats a good idea! but if I understand you correctly I think I would still encounter this issue at a small scale. If there are ever  2 block bounding boxes in the same plane it will always be possible to collide with 2 at the same time

Comment: You can have more and more scales and have to keep scaling down until you only have one collision left.

Comment: Ah ok, that sounds pretty advanced

Comment: From all my research on XNA collision detection, that was the most useful and reliable method. And it is quite simple to implement, as you do the "same thing" but just with another set of boxes...

Comment: I hope it is clear that I am now talking about scaling the bounding boxes of the ship and not of the blocks.

Comment: Yeah, cheers! Though I'm not gonna implement that at the moment as I need to finish up what I have on this for tomorrow

Comment: Maybe a small addition. If you scale down to a "very small scale" and don't have any smaller scale but still get two collisions, then you might as well just choose the "first" collision box at random, since I don't see a reason why in a small scale the exact box could be important.